# Why is my H-Bridge driver coupling low input into the high side?

Tags: driver, h-bridge

I have struggling for about a week with this problem and I am not sure how to fix it , so stack exchange community please help :).

Ok so basically I am making a h-bridge using 4-N channel mosfets, and in order to drive the high side I am using [IRS2001](http://www.irf.com/product-info/datasheets/data/irs2001pbf.pdf) High and Low side drivers.

Here is my schematic :
[image]

Larger pic : https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayE0L.png

Here is an updated schematic of how my signals are inputted :

[image]

Larger pic : https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkNCB.png

I am using a 5kHz PWM signal to switch on for about 0.5secs and then turn off the mosfets to drive the motor in one direction and vice versa for the other direction.

The motor seems fine but when I probe the input and out of the gate driver I see problems.

The low output seems to couple with the high side output even though the high input signal is clean as shown in the oscilloscope output below.

Another question i have is what are the best capacitors to be using for this mosfet driver, at the moment i am using an electrolytic type capacitor around 10uF, is this applicable?

[image]

- The green signal is the HO  ( high output signal)
- The yellow signal is the HIN ( high input signal)

[image]

- The blue signal is the LIN( low in signal)

Here is where I am probing

[image]

So my question really is , why is this happening and how can I solve this ? Thanks

Comment: How are you probing? You have large currents, and high edge rates, which means your probe ground can easily couple in to your probed "signal" **very** easily. You're not using the ground clip wire, are you?

Comment: Why does your motor appear to have four leads? Also, do you understand that the high output is *relative* to Vx? If Vx is varying, the high output will vary, too, regardless of what's happening on HIN.

Comment: Umm yeah i am using the ground clip wire , should I not ? I'll post a picture of how i'm doing it in a minute let me take a photo on my iPhone .

Comment: @DaveTweed was in a hurry messed up on paint , should be just TWO leads , What is this Vx you are referring to ?

Comment: Vx is the pin between LO and HO on the driver chip.

Comment: @DaveTweed oh its Vs in the picture, sorry i dont understand this statement "If Vx is varying, the high output will vary, too, regardless of what's happening on HIN" . Do you think my Vs is varying because I am also feeding the PWM to the low side ?

Comment: It all looks like it should do to me. Read what Dave tweed says in his comment. @DaveTweed - this is the answer methinks

Comment: Sorry, yes, it's Vs, not Vx. It varies because it's connected directly to the motor terminal, and yes, this varies indirectly because of the activity of the low-side driver.

Comment: I have a very strong sneaking suspicion that you are dealing with freewheeling here. The motor is being turned on, current flows for a while, then the MOSFETs are turned off, the motor dumps the energy in its magnetic field through the body diodes of your FETs and when that's done the Vs nodes start floating at Vcc/2 (in this case 6V).

Comment: @user26129 when i zoom in on the coupled signal its a perfect square wave with 5khz and it has 12V amplitude looking at the scope ,  according to DaveTweed this floating will affect the HO if the gate driver but if its motor energy being dumped it wouldn't be doing it at 5khz square wave or would it ?

Comment: @subz I think I was wrong then. I think we are missing some information. How are you driving all four FETs, can you show (or maybe update your question) with the exact waveforms going into both HIN and LIN ports?

Comment: @DaveTweed so can i fix this problem by making low side active high instead of putting PWM ?

Comment: @user26129 i dont have the exact input waveforms with me at the moment , i have updated the schematic, but basically low in signal is a phase shifted signal of the high in signal as shown above, the low in signal occurs at the same time you see the weird half amplitude signal (they are in phase) .

Comment: Why do you feel that this is a problem? It's actually supposed to work this way. If you want to see the actual gate drive to the upper transistor, you need to make a *differential* measurement between Vs and HO.

Comment: Be sure to not use a high duty cycle, as the upper switches cannot sustain much time saturated, and the boot-strap capacitor is charged at the low switches on-time. This is a common mistake with boot-strap.

Comment: @DaveTweed this is a problem because the coupled signal is actually causing the other side mosfet to conduct slightly , this effect can be seen at the load.  But now i changed the design a bit and only putting in an active high at the low side (not PWM ) when one side is on and is beginning to work normal and I do not see those weird coupled signals anymore.  Still not sure how this fixed it tho.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are measuring the correct. Because high side MOSFET is off and low side MOSFET is switching middle point(VX in your case) voltage will swing between battery voltage and ground.

If you see low pin voltage and vx pin voltage they should be complimentary to each other.

Please post the low side gate voltage and VX voltage (zoomed)

Comment: 'measuring the correct' what? Or do you mean 'your measurement is correct'?